# Is it correct that single-threaded process can use only PCB without touching TCB?

Tags: operating-system

As titled.

Is there any OS implementation that when running a single-threaded program, the OS only uses PCB (Process Control Block) to store all the related information? Since I heard from somewhere else that every OS will create a TCB (Thread Control Block) under a PCB when running even a single-thread program.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct that single-threaded process can use only PCB without touching TCB?

4 common possibilities are:

a) Threads are executable things, a process is just a container (that contains a virtual address space, at least one thread, file handles, etc). In this case it's likely that you'll have something like a PCB and TCB (even when the process only has one thread). Most modern operating systems are like this.

b) "Tasks" are executable things. Processes, threads and a whole pile of weird stuff that are neither (e.g. tasks that share file handles but don't share virtual address spaces) are emulated on top of the underlying "tasks". In this case PCB and TCB (Thread Control Block) don't make sense (you'd have a "Task Control Block" that's like everything merged together). Modern Linux is like this.

c) From kernel's perspective, processes are executable things and threads don't exist/aren't supported (but may be emulated in user-space). In this case TCB doesn't make sense. Old Unix systems (including old versions of Linux) were like this.

d) There's only one process and threads don't exist; and there's no PCB and no TCB. MS-DOS was like this.

Note that there's also uncommon possibilities.